# Create two columns based on single column but not when empty

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, anaconda

Sample data frame:

```
    id                           col1                      col2
0  Bob       2018-11-29 TO 2018-11-30  2018-12-01 TO 2018-12-31
1  James     2018-10-19 TO 2018-10-31                       NaT
2  Jane      2018-04-05 TO 2018-07-12  2018-11-29 TO 2018-11-30
```

I have two columns showing date ranges as:

```
"2018-11-29 TO 2018-11-30"
```

I have extracted each date from the first column successfully into two new columns like so:

```
def my_func(data):
    dates = data.split(" TO ")
    dt1 = pd.to_datetime(dates[0].strip(), format="%Y-%m-%d")
    dt2 = pd.to_datetime(dates[1].strip(), format="%Y-%m-%d")
    return (dt1, dt2)

df[["new_col_1", "new_col_2"]] = df.apply(lambda row: pd.Series(my_func(row["col1"])), axis=1)
```

This worked fine in "col1" because every row has a value. However, in "col2" not every row has a value. I want it to skip those rows but it is not working. I tried using `pd.notnull()` with conditional logic in the lambda statement but I think the `pd.Series()` is throwing it off and it keeps trying to pass the values anyways and I keep getting:

```
AttributeError: ("'float' object has no attribute 'split'", 'occurred at index 0')
```

But the actual `dtype` of the columns ("col1" and "col2") is `object` (string), not float, so I'm not sure why it is giving this error.

How do I modify this so it works but skips rows where this column has no value?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] with sample data that reproduces the problem? Right now the issue is that you are trying to use a `.str` method on a `float` object (probably just a number in your column) so that can't happen

Comment: Also just for your information, `object` does not mean string. It's the dtype that is capable of holding `string`, but it can just as easily hold a variety of different objects, including `float`. `df = pd.DataFrame([True, 'True', 1, 1.00])` will have dtype `object` yet `type(df[0][0])` is `bool`

Comment: I added a sample data frame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need the self-def function

```
#df=pd.DataFrame({'string':["2018-11-29 TO 2018-11-30","2018-11-29 TO 2018-11-30","2018-11-29 TO 2018-11-30"]})
df.string.str.split(' TO ',expand=True).apply(pd.to_datetime)
Out[571]: 
           0          1
0 2018-11-29 2018-11-30
1 2018-11-29 2018-11-30
2 2018-11-29 2018-11-30
#pd.concat([df,df.string.str.split(' TO ',expand=True).apply(pd.to_datetime)],axis=1)
```

Update

```
df1=df.col1.str.split('TO',expand=True).apply(pd.to_datetime,errors='coerce')
df1.columns=['col1_1', 'col1_2']
df2=df.col2.str.split('TO',expand=True).apply(pd.to_datetime,errors='coerce')
df2.columns=['col2_1', 'col2_2']
pd.concat([df,df1,df2],1)
Out[578]: 
      id                    col1    ...              0          1
0    Bob  2018-11-29TO2018-11-30    ...     2018-12-01 2018-12-31
1  James  2018-10-19TO2018-10-31    ...            NaT        NaT
2   Jane  2018-04-05TO2018-07-12    ...     2018-11-29 2018-11-30
[3 rows x 7 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks! But what would I do if some values are blank/empty?

Comment: @ArthurDent https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html try check with `errors='coerce'`

Comment: Sorry, just having trouble applying because it can't be applied to every column, only to two columns.

Comment: @ArthurDent you have two column , so you need do above str.split two times . then should be ok

Comment: I added sample data frame.

Comment: Is this creating new dataframes? I just want to add new columns. That is what my existing solution does for col1. Sorry I am confused how to apply this because it changes even the working solution. I want to be able to name the resulting columns and add to existing dataframe - just like in my example: `df[["new_col_1", "new_col_2"]] = df.apply(lambda row: pd.Series(my_func(row["col1"])), axis=1)`

Comment: @ArthurDent I am not sure what you need now...pd.concat, is just create your new column ..

Comment: Sorry for all the trouble. I *waaay* over-complicated this in my head. This is a much simpler and more elegant solution.